# Some suspicious software making request to nmcheck.gnome.org

Tags: 18.04, security, malware

In the last few days, my system has started popping up an Ubuntu default web-browser and making a request to nmcheck.gnome.org website and immediately shutting off.

Since this happened, I cannot run system updates.

Also, I am a `php` developer and cannot run `composer install` or `composer update`

[image: sudo apt update]

[image: software update]

How can I find this script and delete it forever?

Comment: Chech which plugin's / add-on's there are installed in your browser(s).

Comment: I am using Firefox and I already disabled each extension but it is not opening Firefox it is using Ubuntu default browser

Comment: What leads you to believe that "Ubuntu software update blocked my IP"?  Please answer questions by editing your original question. Comments are not intended for conversation.

Comment: Most Linux distributions come with Firefox installed and set as the default browser.

Comment: `sudo lsof -i` will show internet connections. Adding `namechk.com` to your `/etc/hosts` with an IP of `127.0.0.1` will prevent the connection.

Comment: suddenly one time this popup browser did not shut and I finally know the url of the request and it is `nmcheck.gnome.org`, sorry previously I can not see url properly. Thank you

Comment: Sorry but you mention namechk.com and nmcheck.gnome.org. Which is it?

Comment: `nmcheck.gnome.org` for sure previously I did not see the url properly so I search nmcheck in google and it suggested me `namechk.com` but it is `nmcheck.gnome.org` for sure

Comment: Typically, you should use `sudo netstat -tulpan` to see connection and corresponding process name and PID that make the connection.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[nmcheck.gnome.org](http://nmcheck.gnome.org/) is not malware. It is the gnome network manager connectivity check (for captive portals/hotspots). Click the link and you will see a single text file with a text in it. It should be "NetworkManager is online".

Check `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`. There probably is a section with this in it:

```
[Connectivity] 
uri=http://nmcheck.gnome.org/check_network_status.txt
```

Comment: any suggestion why software update is not running?

Comment: This feature is weird

Comment: No such line in `NetworkManager.conf.` and my popup happens on a standard always-live RJ45-to-router-to-large-ISP connection. https://imgur.com/a/hTQ2aiu

Comment: please do not use rules for Ubuntu 18.04 for 20.04 ;-) It probably is set differently in 20.04

Comment: It should at least use SSL.

Comment: @bakcsa83 Wi-Fi/hotspot login usually don't support SSL.

Answer (score 28):

on Ubuntu 20.04 no `[Connectivity]`  line like accepted answer in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.

But you can disable the auto connectivity check  by:

1. Go to `Settings` app
2. Go to `Privacy` menu
3. On `Connectivity` tab, uncheck `Connectivity Checking`

Comment: Actually there is, if you type `NetworkManager --print-config` you'll see that option, it's just that's inside `/etc/NeworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity.conf`.

Answer (score 9):

nmcheck.gnome.org is a host used by NetworkManager to verify that it has Internet connectivity. gnome.org is owned by the Gnome project. This is *not* a suspicious domain.

nmcheck.gnome.org hosts a single file; [network_status.txt](http://nmcheck.gnome.org/check_network_status.txt), which indicates that NM is actually connected to the Internet.

In short, nothing to worry over.

Comment: but it is alway popup around 5 minutes and this is occurring all of a sudden still I can not update software see image That I have attached

Comment: any suggestion why software update is not running?

Comment: I suggest that you ask your *actual* question, and not what you imagine the problem to be. Make a new question (or edit the current one) about why updates fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is painful when connecting to public or free hotspots, of course until you "log on" there is no DNS so this always fails.

It can also pop up during modem/router boots or when the wifi NIC has issues.

If it happens at the same time every day then something is going offline or rebooting. Maybe a firmware push check.