# Hotspot Login - http://nmcheck.gnome.org - 404 Not Found nginx/118.0

Tags: nginx

I am new to linux, maybe someone can help me out with this new challenge.

A white screen randomly pops up with the following info

---

Hotspot Login

http://nmcheck.gnome.org

**404 Not Found**

nginx/118.0

---

Will sudo apt-get install nginx solve the issue?

I am an Ubuntu 20.04 user (no sure if this is even related)

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Some suspicious software making request to nmcheck.gnome.org](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070823/some-suspicious-software-making-request-to-nmcheck-gnome-org)

Comment: And no, do not install nginx unless you need it and know how to manage it.

Comment: It should not return a 404 is it possible something is broken on GNOME server sides ?

Comment: On this thread on Ubuntu forum they recommend to disable the connection check untill another fix is found https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2473318

Answer (score 3):

`sudo apt install nginx` **does not solve** the Hotspot login 404 issue.

You may disable the connectivity checking in Settings > Privacy > Connectivity

- if disabled your box will not be able to detect hotspots and some network connectivity errors
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this today so its happening again.
When you see Nginx 404 error that's on the server side not yours.

You DO NOT want to turn off "Connectivity Checking" as mentioned because it will impact ubuntu's ability to detect HotSpot logins at hotels, etc.  A proper workaround would be to add nmcheck.gnome.org to your host file and point it to some other public IP like gnome.org itself or google.com until the nmcheck site is restored.

```
# host google.com
google.com has address 142.250.72.238

# sudo echo "142.250.72.238  nmcheck.gnome.org"  >> /etc/hosts
```

This is a temporary workaround but now when you disconnect and reconnect your internet connection it will act normally when hotspots are detected.